# Finding impulse response

Tags: matlab

This is my first time using MATLAB in an engineering course, and I have one little problem from Fourier and Laplace transforms.

[image: problem description]

For the first part (a), I got the transfer function by myself and the answer was:

```
 H(s) = (1)/(1+s)
 H(jw)= (1)/(1+jw)
 the magnitude = 1/(sqrt(1^2+w^2))
```

Is the first part correct?  I hope I can get the simplest code for the other parts so I can understand how to use MATLAB. Note that I am using symbolic math.

Answer (score 0):

The most important is that you have the transfer function. Once you have the transfer function, for the part (a) you have [bode](http://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/bode.html), for the part (b) and (c), you can see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/examples/plotting-system-responses.html). For the part (d), you can use [laplace](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/laplace.html) to recalculate the transfer function.